# sourcecpp cannot find 'RcppArmadillo.h', but cxxfunction can

Tags: rcpp

I have run into this weird problem: when I try to use my `sourcecpp()` on my cpp file, it will generate this error: **fatal error: 'RcppArmadillo.h' file not found**.

My cpp file is something like this

```
#include "RcppArmadillo.h"
// [[ Rcpp :: depends ( RcppArmadillo )]]
using namespace arma;
using namespace Rcpp;
...
```

But I am pretty sure that I have my `RcppArmadillo.h` and the weird thing is, if I compile the function using `cxxfunction(..., plugin="RcppArmadillo")`, everything will work just fine.

Even more weird is that after I ran `cxxfunction()` function, `sourcecpp()` will suddenly work on all my cpp files using `RcppArmadillo.h`.

What is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works with regular expression and by adding all those spaces you **break** the regular expression for the plugin via `Rcpp::depends()`.

There are dozens of posted examples; start from what works. Take for example [this simple example from the Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/armadillo-eigenvalues/) and place the following into, say, `/tmp/armaeigen.cpp`:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec getEigenValues(arma::mat M) {
    return arma::eig_sym(M);
}

/*** R
set.seed(42)
X <- matrix(rnorm(4*4), 4, 4)
Z <- X %*% t(X)
getEigenValues(Z)
*/
```

The `sourceCpp("/tmp/armaeigen.cpp")` not only works (ie compiles, links and loads) but also runs the embedded example for you:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/armaeigen.cpp")

R> set.seed(42)

R> X <- matrix(rnorm(4*4), 4, 4)

R> Z <- X %*% t(X)

R> getEigenValues(Z)
          [,1]
[1,]  0.331887
[2,]  1.685588
[3,]  2.409920
[4,] 14.210011
R>
```

The Rcpp Attributes vignette has all the details.

Comment: That solves my problem! Must have carelessly copied that wrong expression from somewhere. Thx and will definitely read the vignette.